# Facebook SDK for iOS 4.2 to latest

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

So, I just downloaded the new Facebook iOS SDK version 3.1. When I run a sample code, it complains about Social.framework that doesn't exist in my Xcode 4.4

I already have Xcode 4.5, but the problem is, Xcode 4.5 doesn't allow us to use iOS 4.2. And I need to run it on iOS 4.2.

So, if I use old Facebook SDK, that can run on Xcode 4.4, will Apple reject it?

Apple is so difficult these days.

Comment: Apple is reject any app that support the iPhone 5 screen resolution compiled with iOS 5 SDK. The problem being that if you want to support iOS 6 you will need to drop support ARMv6 and iOs 4.2. You can set the deployment target to 4.3 in iOS 6 SDK. In short, want iOS 6 support  (the latest facebook SDK) then drop support for iOS 4.2 or lower.

Comment: It doesn't mean we want iOS 6 support, because old Facebook SDK is already good enough for us. But, I'm just asking whether Apple will reject it because we don't support the new Facebook iOS SDK flow.

Comment: No I don't think they will reject your app just because you are not using the latest facebook SDK. Since you do not target iOS 6 there will be no way for you to support the native facebook sdk thus they can't reject your app for not using something that's not available. They might reject your app for not supporting the iPhone 5

Comment: That's right. They don't reject the app. Thanks rckoenes!